# React: Importing modules with object destructuring, or individually?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, npm, material-ui

In React, some packages allow you to import Components using either individual assignment: `import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card"`, or via object destructuring: `import { Card } from "@material-ui/core"`.

I read in a Blog that using the object destructuring syntax can have performance ramifications if your environment doesn't have proper tree-shaking functionality. The result being that *every* component of `@material-ui/core` is imported, not just the one you wanted.

In what situations could using object destructuring imports cause a decline in application performance and how serious would the impact be? Also, in an environment that *does* have all the bells and whistles, like the default create-react-app configuration, will using one over the other make *any* difference at all?

Comment: Those imports aren't equivalent.  One will load the file given by `material-ui/core/Card` and then put the default export into `Card`.  The other will load the file given by `material-ui/core` and try to get the exported `Card` symbol.  Additionally, I suspect you're using webpack since you have `@` in your import statements which adds additional complexity to your question.  Do you want your question with respect to how webpack handles `import` or how the spec does?

Comment: Yes webpack is what's included in create-react-app which is what I'm using to boostrap. Although contrary to looking like the name of a webpack plugin, material-ui is just a regular Node package with a collection of UI elements. Like Boostrap or Materialize. I'm curious if it would make _any_ difference when using webpack, but what effect it would have if I wasnt using webpack.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you aren't destructuring whenever you import with the `{}`.  You can't do deep destructuring using this syntax.  The `{}` get named exports.  The syntax there is special which is why you can use the `as` statement.

Comment: Ok interesting, thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on package internal structure is often discouraged but it's [officially valid](https://material-ui.com/api/card/) in Material UI:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
```

In order to not depend on this and keep imports shorter, top-level exports can be used

```
import { Card } from "@material-ui/core"
```

Both are interchangeable, *as long as the setup supports tree-shaking*. In case unused top-level exports can be tree-shaken, the second option is preferable. Otherwise the the first option is preferable, it guarantees unused package imports to not be included into the bundle.

create-react-app uses Webpack configuration that supports tree-shaking and can benefit from the second option.

Comment: Is this also true for development mode for current CRA (v3.4.3)?

Comment: @olefrank Are you asking about tree shaking? It shouldn't occur in development mode, it increases build time and the outcome is reduced bundle size which isn't important for dev mode.

Comment: According to https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/: Development bundles can contain the full library which can lead to slower startup times. I want fastest possible startup time when developing

Comment: @olefrank On the other hand importing from module's main entry point makes it easier to maintain and provides some options, e.g. `@material-ui/core` can be aliased to `@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js` in CRA config for dev env and potentially improve build time while load time will still be reasonable for local development. If you're still able to see the improvements in dev with the first import then prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Loading in extra code, such as numerous components from material-ui you may not need, has two primary performance impacts: Download time, and execution time.

Download time is simple: Your JS file(s) are larger, therefore take longer to download, especially over slower connections such as mobile. Properly slimming down your JS using mechanisms like tree shaking is always a good idea.

Execution time is a little less apparent, but also has a similar effect, this time to browsers with less computing power available - again, primarily mobile. Even if the components are never used, the browser must still parse and execute the source and pull it into memory. On your desktop with a powerful processor and plenty of memory you'll probably never notice the difference, but on a slower/older computer or mobile device you may notice a small lag even after the file(s) finish downloading as they are processed.

Assuming your build tooling has properly working tree shaking, my opinion is generally they are roughly equivalent. The build tool will not include the unused components into the compiled JS, so it shouldn't impact either download or execution time.